# How do you perform mediation analysis with multiple treatments in R

Tags: r, regression

I would like to analyze data from an experiment using mediation analysis in R.  However, the experimental design is a full factorial design across three variables (two continuous, one categorical) and I cannot find an explanation of how to implement mediation in R with multiple treatments.  I have read the documentation on the `mediation` package but they do not appear to provide ways of expanding `X` beyond a single treatment.  Similarly, I cannnot find a way to do that in `MBESS` or `lavaan` packages.

I found a very recent article that discusses the statistical theory/approaches necessary to implement multiple treatments in mediation analysis, Hayes and Preacher 2014 (http://quantpsy.org/pubs/hayes_preacher_2014.pdf) but, unfortunately, they only give code implementations of their approach in Mplus, SPSS and SAS.  I need to implement this in the next couple days for a presentation so I don't have time to get up to speed on another program to do it, I need to implement it in R.

Does anyone know if there is an implementation in R that I've missed?
Or if there is a way to implement this approach outside of a package?

(I realize I could convert my full factorial design into a single treatment by treating each 3-factor combination as a level but such an analysis would not be helpful.)

Comment: Did you see the function multimed?  Also, the function "findFn" from SOS package can be used to locate packages, e.g., findFn("mediation")  http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mediation/docs/multimed.  See bmem.mi also...

Comment: Thanks, these were helpful ways to research further, though I didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

After more exhaustive search, it appears that there is not currently an R package that can handle mediation with multiple treatments (ie, predictors).  Packages in R that can do mediation include: `mediation`, `MBESS`, `lavaan`, `multimed`, `bmem`, and `OpenMx`.  However, it appears that those that handle multiple predictors (e.g., `OpenMx`) also require a model coded as a RAM path model.  This is the type of model needed to code full path analyses and is notably more complex than simplified mediation model coding (e.g. in `mediation`) that I was hoping for.

Comment: I just skimmed the paper, but on the surface this approach appears similar to partially / hidden markov modeling with latent states for longitudinal data.  There are a number of Markov model packages.  LMest package simulates Markov models for latent categorical data.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - I may end up going the route of trying to implement that method in R as opposed to a full RAM model/SEM approach.